# Where upper() (or any other) function is located in the source code?

Tags: python, function

For introspection purpose, how I could locate upper() function in Python's source code?

Comment: Note that these methods on built-in types, depending on the implementation you're using, probably are not written in Python.

Comment: `upper` is a python method of `str` which is builtin Type. Builtin Types are generally written in `C` and source for builtin types cannot be accessed from compiled python. You can look at source code for implementation.